# Should I set an index on the data covered by the multi-column index?

Tags: sql, database, indexing

Suppose that I have a simple table that describes people - Persons.

This table has three columns:

```
Person_id, name, surname
```

I want to create an index on this table. I know that queries directed to this table will search persons based on names (`WHERE name = 'sth'`) and based on both names and surnames (`WHERE name = 'sth' AND surname = 'sth'`).

So I created the index on the columns `(name, surname)`. In this case should I add an additional index only on the column `(name)`?

Comment: It might depend on the specific database you're using. But for most database using a predicate on name will use the index on (name,surname). As opposed to a predicate on surname which generally won't be using that index ( oracle might use SKIP_SCAN and use that index even if the leading column was not provided). If storage is an issue you might want consider not even indexing surname depending on your use case if it's not really discriminating.

Comment: A compound index can be used in cases where the **n left-most columns** of the index are specified - so an index on `(name, surname)` will work for both queries on just `name`, as well as queries on `name` and `surname`. No need for an additional index. However, this compound index will **NOT** work for queries that would select based on solely the `surname` - if you have such queries, you might need another index (on `surname` alone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for two indexes.  The single compound index will handle conditions on both `name` and `name`/`surname` -- as long as `name` is the first column in the index.

This should be true in any database.

MySQL has a pretty good [explanation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) of multi-column indexes; it might help you understand them better.

I should note that this refers to the b-tree index, which is the default and standard index in almost every database that supports indexes.  It does not necessarily apply to all indexes.  For instance, hash-based indexes do not have this property.